# Cannot find local variable while debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, build.gradle

I'm trying to debug my application with the option `Java Field Watchpoints`. My variable is found first time it appears in my code (its initialisation) but right after that I've got this error:

> Cannot find local variable 'variableName'

and I can't follow its modifications then.

I've been searching around and modified my gradle file as this:

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       debug {
           minifyEnabled false
           debuggable true
           testCoverageEnabled = true
       }
   }
```

My active build variant is `debug` (not release) so the error is not coming from here.
I am using `Android Studio 3.6` Canary 11

Does anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Why using canary while u can use `3.6` the stable one?  - Are u facing the same with stable version?

Comment: Is is possible that you've declared a variable in your function, and once you're out of the function you except to see the value of this variable ? Because it does sounds like it.

Comment: There is a bug in Android Studio 3.6.1 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144888077 . As workaround you can print stuff to debug or create a class level function and pass your variable to it and put debugger in that function.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a optimization by some part of the tool chain, like removing dead code, escape analysis, or indeed a bug in the runtime, see for some of the possibilities: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/proguard-and-r8

Maybe unit testing your code and annotating it with debug logging will prove to be more successful.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit different case but the message might also indicate you have modified data viewers of how objects/nodes are rendered within IDE (especially when debugging).

`Unable to evaluate the expression Cannot find local variable 'JsonAutoDetect'`

I happened to forget I made a custom renderer to read Java objects as JSONs.

The solution was to 'Use default renderer' or just disable the renderer.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your variable is going out of scope:
 if it is declared inside a local scope such as a loop or if else or a try block or any kind of block with braces inside a function. So if after you initialize the variable, the next executed statement is outside that block, your variable is no longer visible and cannot be accessed (that's the way local variables work in Java). So not a bug.
 To verify you can declare the variable at the class level and do the initialization in the local block. The variable will still be accessible outside of the local block.

```
class MyClass{
  private MyObject myObject;

  public void myFunction(){
          if(....){
            myObject = new MyObject();
          }else{
          }
  }
}
```

Comment: afaik there is a thing in bytecode called local variable table, which exists for debugging, so it's either android java/kotlin compiler or android studio bug

Comment: I don't follow, can you clarify? Do you mean that having a local variable table in the debugger will prevent a variable from going out of scope and always be shown on that table?

Comment: question is about local variable, try to declare one and see for yourself, there is no need for it to be out of scope, can be just declaration of variable, then printing some stuff, then passing of those variable to a function. if you stop debugger on printing or passing, you will get that error.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share a sample class and highlight the offending line as I'm unable to reproduce.